# How do I get the console output visible in Oracle Developer IDE?

Tags: oracle11g

I am a newb to Oracle. I used to use SQL Plus, and use `set serveroutput on` to see the results. However, when I started using Oracle Developer, my queries would run, however, I was not able to see the console or the results:

```
select *
from customer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean "Oracle SQL Developer" application.
If yes, the in SQL Developer click on View option, then select Dbms output
[image]

DBMS Output window (panel) should appear somewhere on the screen.
Then, click on green plus sing in the DBMS-Output panel, and select a session you want to spy.
[image]